# How to paste '.' Symbol using protractor Node js

Tags: node.js, automation, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

I am trying to enter some text in the input text box as <@#$%^&.> But when I try to use a protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v", it is not working. And the application is build using angular js and the input text box accepts text.

I am getting the below error
TypeError : TypeError: Cannot read property '>' of undefined

How to enter dot symbol using node js in Protractor framework

Comment: paste your code

Comment: return strAvailability ? (element(eval(targetElement)).sendKeys(evData, protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v")), browser.waitForAngular) : console.log(colors.bgRed("Element is not displayed or out-of-the-view" + "\n" +
                        "Please check the locator information for :" + element));
                   
                });

Comment: this syntax is very unusual and it's impossible to properly debug it. I'd recommend you to reconsider it first

Comment: I want to enter 12.09 to an input text box using node js protractor. Can I have the proper syntax?

Comment: as official documentation https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys states it's just `element(by.locator(locator)).sendKeys("12.09")`

Comment: what you are doing is better done using `if/else` blocks. your `browser.waitForAngular` literally does nothing, since you don't invoke it. Even if you did? I don't understand the advantage of putting it on the same line with sendKeys